# Nasm division operator `/`

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

Nasm has division operators, but are they integer division. E.g. will `5/2 == 2`?

[/ and // are both division operators: / is unsigned division and // is signed division. Similarly, % and %% provide unsigned and signed modulo operators respectively.](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at the [NASM source code](https://github.com/sezero/nasm/blob/master/asm/eval.c#L661), the operands are cast to `int64_t` or `uint64_t`. In other words: yes, they are integer divisions.

---

<sup>Disclaimer: The code I linked to isn't the official NASM repo, so you might want to cross-check this against the official NASM source code to be 100% sure.</sup>